# Loading and storing words in assembly

Tags: arrays, sorting, assembly, mips, instructions

I'm not sure what is exactly happening in my code. The problem arises when I try to swap the values in the array using `lw` and `sw`. The program is supposed to sort the array in ascending order and then output it.

```
.text
.globl __start
__start:

    la $t0, array                 # t0 = address of array
    lw $t1, count                 # t1 = count, exit loop when it goes to 0

    loop:  
        lw $t2, ($t0)             # t2 = element in array

        lw $t4, count             # t4 = count, for innerLoop
        add $t3, $t0, 4           # t3 = address of next array element

        innerLoop: 
            lw $t5, ($t3)         # t5 = element in array

            ble $t2, $t5, greater # if element in t2 is >= element in t5 goto greater
            sw $t2, ($t3)         # store element in t2 into the t3 array address
            sw $t5, ($t0)         # store element in t5 into the t0 array address
            lw $t2, ($t0)         # t2 = new element in t0 array address

            greater:
            add $t4, $t4, -1      # t1 -- -> counter --
            add $t3, $t3, 4       # t3 = address of next array element 
            bnez $t4, innerLoop   # if innerLoop count != 0 go to innerLoop

        add $t1, $t1, -1          # t1 -- -> counter --
        addi $t0, $t0, 4          # t0 = address of next array element
        bnez $t1, loop            # if loop count != 0 go to loop

    la $t0, array                 # t0 = address of array
    lw $t1, count                 # t1 = count, exit loop when it goes to 0

    lw $t2, ($t0)                 # lw in address t0 into t2
    move $a0, $t2                 # Display the first element in array 
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    add $t1, $t1, -1              # t1 -- -> counter --
    add $t0, $t0, 4               # increment counter to point to next word

    displayLoop:    
        lw $t2, ($t0)             # t2 = next element in array

        la $a0, comma             # Display ", "
        li $v0, 4                 # a0 = address of message
        syscall                   # v0 = 4 which indicates display a string

        move $a0, $t2             # Display element in array 
        li $v0, 1
        syscall

        add $t1, $t1, -1          # t1 -- -> counter --
        add $t0, $t0, 4           # increment counter to point to next word
        bnez $t1, displayLoop     # if count != 0 the go to displayLoop

    la $a0, crlf                  # Display "cr/lf"
    li $v0, 4                     # a0 = address of message
    syscall                       # v0 = 4 which indicates display a string

    li $v0, 10                    # End Of Program
    syscall 

.data
array: .word 3, 4, 2, 6, 12, 7, 18, 26, 2, 14, 19, 7, 8, 12, 13
count: .word 15
comma: .asciiz ", "
crlf:   .asciiz "\n"
```

This is the output I'm getting:

> `2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26, 167780396, 19, 18, 15, 14, 13, 12, 12, 8, 7`

Comment: You run your inner loop `count` times even though there aren't that many elements available to check.

Comment: yes you are right now I fixed that by changing the line add $t4,$t4,-1 to add $t4,$t1,-1 however I'm not getting any output at all now

Comment: `add $t4,$t1,-1` is obviously not going to work, because `$t1` never changes in the inner loop, so you'll just end up with an infinite loop. You need to make sure that `$t4` contains the actual number of elements left to check _before_ entering the inner loop.

Comment: $t1 doesn't need to change in the innerloop because t4 is the count for the inner loop and it goes down by 1 every iteration and then when it jumps back out to the outer loop t1 goes down by one and t4 is set to 1 less then t1 because the inner loop is looking at the next element while the outerloop looks at the one element.

Comment: If it helps PCSpim tells me there is an error at the line lw $t5, ($t3) when I want t5 to hold the element at the t3 address

Comment: I solved it. I need the check to run loop again to check if t1 is greater than 1 not if it wasn't equal to 0 because when it equaled 1 t3 was equal to 4 passed the end of the array

Comment: _"$t1 doesn't need to change in the innerloop because t4 is the count for the inner loop and it goes down by 1 every iteration"_ If you had used `add $t4,$t1,-1` it wouldn't go down. `add $t4,$t1,-1` means `$t4 = $t1 - 1`, and since `$t1` is constant throughout the inner loop, so is `$t1 - 1`.

Comment: Post an answer to resolve this question as to how you solved it if you don't mind.

Comment: Add $t4,$t1,-1 isn't inside the inner loop. It is right before the inner loop inside the outer loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the outer loop if statement to check if t1 is greater than 1 because when it gets down to one t0 is at the last element in the array and nothing else need to be checked